# Calculate the number of subscribers that can be supported by a cell with 400 radio channels

Tags: cellular-network

Estimate the number of subscribers that can be supported by a cell with 400 radio channels.
Assume each subscriber generates on an average 2.5 calls per hour with call holding time of
120 seconds. Assume 2% blocking.

Comment: You appear to have misunderstood what this site is for.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).